# Swift class in Cocoa Touch Objective-C Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to build a Cocoa Touch Framwork (XCode 6, obviously) with Objective-C and some Swift classes.

I've successfully added Swift classes to regular projects (no framworks) before so I'm aware of the build settings required for this (**Embedded Content Contains Swift Code**). Unfortunately, the framework project doesn't build the header file (**projectName-Swift.h**) and I'm not able to import the class and the Swift classes into any of my .m files.

Does anybody know why this wouldn't work, and what build settings I need to change in order to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer;

Within the frameworks the import statement for Swift files has to look as follows;

```
#import <ProjectName/ProjectName-Swift.h>
```

instead of

```
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Sometimes it helps to RTFM (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_82)

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this for a while because I don't think the documentation is clear. I have a slightly different project setup, and it's taken me a while to work this out so I thought I'd answer here.

I have a project with name: MyProject
In this project, I have a framework: MyFramwork

I have a swift file in MyFramework which I want to import into an objective c file in MyFramework.

To do this, you need:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>
```

NOT

```
#import <MyProject/MyFramework-Swift.h>
```

Hope that helps someone.